Internal error in Cloud Firestore (24.10.0) - android.database.CursorWindowAllocationException: Cursor window allocation
My app is published for 2 years now and I just cannot wrap my head around this error message which I'm getting rarely, but steadly since the first day of publication.
It says, "Internal Error" so I don't even know if am I able to do anything with it or is this a Firebase bug.
I'm using Firebase like this way:
   implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.7.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appcheck-playintegrity'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appcheck-debug'

The full stacktrace doesn't even contains any of my code:
   Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Internal error in Cloud Firestore (24.10.0).
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue.lambda$panic$3(AsyncQueue.java:545)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)


Caused by java.lang.RuntimeException: android.database.CursorWindowAllocationException: Cursor window allocation of 2097152 bytes failed. 
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor.lambda$executeAndReportResult$1(AsyncQueue.java:333)
       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:458)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.processTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1187)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor$DelayedStartFactory.run(AsyncQueue.java:235)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:784)


Caused by android.database.CursorWindowAllocationException: Cursor window allocation of 2097152 bytes failed. 
       at android.database.CursorWindow.<init>(CursorWindow.java:136)
       at android.database.CursorWindow.<init>(CursorWindow.java:114)
       at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.clearOrCreateWindow(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:198)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:143)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:137)
       at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition(AbstractCursor.java:220)
       at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToNext(AbstractCursor.java:269)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.SQLitePersistence$Query.forEach(SQLitePersistence.java:493)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.SQLiteRemoteDocumentCache.getAll(SQLiteRemoteDocumentCache.java:143)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.LocalStore.lambda$writeLocally$2(LocalStore.java:248)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.SQLitePersistence.runTransaction(SQLitePersistence.java:228)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.LocalStore.writeLocally(LocalStore.java:240)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.SyncEngine.writeMutations(SyncEngine.java:286)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.FirestoreClient.lambda$write$12(FirestoreClient.java:233)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue.lambda$enqueue$2(AsyncQueue.java:444)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor.lambda$executeAndReportResult$1(AsyncQueue.java:330)
       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:458)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.processTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1187)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor$DelayedStartFactory.run(AsyncQueue.java:235)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:784)

So what can I do to fix this? If I can do anything?

The error "Cursor window allocation of 2097152 bytes failed" indicates that Firestore's internal SQLite operations are attempting to allocate a large cursor window but failing due to memory constraints. This issue arises because Firestore uses SQLite under the hood to store and manage data locally (cache).
The crash might be due to:
Large Query Results: A single Firestore query fetching a large dataset.
Memory Usage Constraints: The device running out of available memory for this operation.
Internal Firestore Bug: Potential inefficiencies in the way Firestore handles local data in its SQLite database.
Suggested Solutions:
Optimize Queries:
Ensure Firestore queries are well-optimized to limit the amount of data being fetched.
Use pagination for large datasets:
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("yourCollection")
    .orderBy("field")
    .limit(50) // Fetch data in batches
    .get()

Disable Local Persistence (if feasible):
If local persistence is not critical for your app, consider disabling it. This avoids SQLite operations altogether:
FirebaseFirestoreSettings settings = new FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder()
    .setPersistenceEnabled(false)
    .build();
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().setFirestoreSettings(settings);

this consider as general guidelines also if have additional information please provide us with
